# Как скачать выписки ZIP из Росреестра с помощью PHP

Tags: php, zip, росреестр

**Задача такая:**

Скачать выписку из Росреестра (ZIP c ЭЦП) и сохранить на локальный диск.
есть программа, которая позволяет по одному GET запросу получить выписку по номеру заявки фгис.

**Проблема заключается в следующем:**

если заказ готов, в ответ на запрос приходит заголовок `Content-type: application/zip` и контент самого зип файла.

а если заказ не готов или какая либо ошибка, то приходит `Content-type: application/json` и контентом является код ошибки.

**Теперь вопрос:**

как при получении ответа на запрос проверить заголовок `content-type` и только в случае `application/zip` сохранить контент в виде файла?

мой код выглядит так:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents("http://localhost:5533/мой-ключ-фгиса/80-107535221");
file_put_contents('/home/rosreestr-zip-files/80-107535221.zip', $content);
```

PS, программа о которой идет речь называется **FgisDownloader**.
источник: https://github.com/harimahari/FgisDownloader

Comment: воспользуйтесь curl

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php

Answer (score 1):

Заголовки запроса можно получить, используя зарезервированную переменную [`$http_response_header`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php). Далее вам потребуется извлечь оттуда нужные заголовок `content-type` и на его основе уже принимать решение, сохранять ответ или нет. Ориентироваться надо не на индексы в массиве (которые могут изменяться), а на поиск вхождения `Content-type:` в саму строку значения.

*зы: скорее всего тип ответа вообще можно определить банально по длине. Если json имеет длину пару десятков-сотен байт, то zip там явно килобайты-мегабайты будет занимать. Но так, конечно, делать не надо.*

Answer (score 0):

## Пример

```php
$headers = get_headers('https://w3.org');

$contentType = getResponseHeader('content-type', $headers);

if ($contentType === 'application/zip') {
    $filename = __DIR__ . '/my_zip.zip';

    $fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
    $ch = curl_init('https://codeload.github.com/laravel/laravel/zip/refs/heads/8.x');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // Optional
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);

    $zipArchive = new ZipArchive();
    $zipArchive->open($filename);
    $zipArchive->extractTo(__DIR__);
    $zipArchive->close();
    unlink($filename);
}


function getResponseHeader(string $header, array $response) : string
{
    foreach ($response as $headerLine) {
        if (stripos($headerLine, $header . ':') === 0) {
            return trim(explode(':', $headerLine, 2)[1]);
        }
    }
    return '';
}
```